# How to run Angular 2 App locally without node

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular, batch-file

So I went through this tutorial making a movie finder app using Angular 2, however we always had to run through 'npm start' in command line.

How do I make it possible for someone to view my project locally in their machine when they don't have Node.js installed?

My project is down below:
https://github.com/Jerick821/moviefinder

I also made the following batch file below which I found online but it doesn't work :(

```
@echo off
cd moviefinder
npm install -g http-server
hs
start http://localhost:1234/
```

How do I make a batch file to run this app?

Comment: Is `npm` a batch file also? if so, use `call mpn install -g http-server` rather than `npm install -g http-server`...

Comment: npm stands for Node Package Manager - if they don't have node installed it's also very likely they don't have npm installed.

Comment: yes they most likely won't have both installed, I would just like to skip the npm process and run this program locally so people can open it straight away. There's probably some code that has to be removed but am not quite sure which one.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Angular QuickStart DEMO at [Angular V2 Quickstart Guide](https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html)

> Try this [QuickStart example on Plunker](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/quickstart/ts/eplnkr.html) without installing anything.

```
<title>Angular Quickstart</title>
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
  body {color:#369;font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;}
</style>

<!-- Polyfills -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.7.4?main=browser"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/systemjs@0.19.39/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
  System.import('main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>

<body>
   <my-app>Loading AppComponent content here ...</my-app>
</body>
```